# New GUI Screen Building, Design and enhancements From Existing Legacy Code

Tags: java, user-interface, ide, legacy-code, gui-builder

All The Gui Builders I heard of in IDES or otherwise would work fine when we start from scratch .

But we have plenty of legacy Java code that has custom dialogs, models, classes for UI . Is there any plugin/tool/Ide or any smart thing that can understand the existing code by analysing it and help us build new GUI Screens and generate code for the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [WindowBuilderPro](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/javadevtools/wbpro/).
It comes as a free Eclipse plugin. 
You can open existing classes which extend JFrame or JPanel by using the "Open with..." dialog.

Another pretty useful tool is the [JFormDesigner](http://www.formdev.com/jformdesigner/). You can use it with Eclipse, JBuilder or IntelliJ plugin, but they also offer a standalone version as well.
But I'm not sure if the JFormDesigner provides reverse engineering because I only tried the 20-days evaluation copy.

Comment: WindowbuilderPro promises reverse engineering , thanx a lot , let me check out how far this would be useful !

Comment: No problem. I've just seen that WindowBuilderPro is included in the Eclipse version (Indigo).